# Print out and make http request only once in a python face recognition script?

Tags: python, face-recognition

First of all, I would like to wish good health to everyone!

I want to create a "party greeter", similar to this one: https://robotzero.one/face-recognition-party-greeter-raspberry-pi/, but using my IP Camera and Ubuntu OS. The intend is to make a web request when a face is recognized. The web request will make echo dot say something using IFTTT.

I am using this script to face recognition: https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/facerec_ipcamera_knn.py

I commented the line 210, because I don't need to see the streaming video, and inserted a print function that shows the name of the found person:

```
        for name, (top, right, bottom, left) in predictions:
          print("- Found {}".format(name))
```

The problem is that when a face is detected it keeps printing the message in the console. Few seconds of a face showing results in dozens of lines in the console with the same message.

I need somehow to limit this and make it shows the message only once. The http request also should be send only once.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Change it to something like this:

```
found_name = None
for name, (top, right, bottom, left) in predictions:
    if name == some_condition:
       found_name = name
       break
print("- Found {}".format(found_name))
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I tried a few things on some_condition, but it failed.